# Why one more assembler instruction for default string

Tags: assembly, rust, compilation

I found interesting behavior.

A call to `default` on a `String` has one more instruction than a call to `to_string` on an empty `&str`. Why?

```rust
pub fn string_default() -> String {
    Default::default()
}

pub fn string_to_string() -> String {
    "".to_string()
}
```

```
example::string_default:
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 8], xmm0
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rcx
        ret

example::string_to_string:
        mov     rax, rdi
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 8], xmm0
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], 1
        ret

.L__unnamed_1:
        .asciz  "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

UPD: build profile 'release'

UPD (2): before rust 1.52.0 the assembler code is the same for both functions (4 instructions). In 1.51.0 and earlier `mov qword` comes before `xorps`.

Comment: Looks like missed optimization. The first code copies the constant `1` from memory, while the second uses an immediate.

Comment: My guess is that `String::default()` is implemented by copying a constant empty string value, while `.to_string()` attempts to construct a new string from scratch leading to the different assembly you see.

Comment: @Locke [`String::default()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2112) is just [`String::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/alloc/string.rs.html#379)

Comment: not the same behavior == not same assembler

Comment: Except of course the assembly code does have the same behavior, it just writes the constant `1` differently.

Comment: I said nothing about 'not the same behavior'. The behavior is the same, but what's wrong with the optimization)

Comment: I'm talking about the Rust code, String::new is not the same semantic then "".to_string() and so expect the same assembler is wrong

Comment: @Stargateur ok, understood :)

Comment: TupleCats: I think Jester was replying to @Stargateur, who suggested the behaviour was different.  When in fact it ultimately isn't.  Different inputs to the optimizer, but the code does end up doing the same thing when compiling for x86-64 with this Rust implementation.  Ideally, the optimizer would make the same asm for both, choosing whichever one is most efficient (the mov-immediate instead of copying from .rodata).  Or are you suggesting that there's a need to copy the current-size field from static storage so it could be different at link-time?

Comment: @Stargateur: Notice that both versions are storing zeros for the last 16 bytes (`xorps xmm0,xmm0`), not copying those from static storage, so I think whatever it's copying from must be `const` or whatever Rust calls it since it's able to do constant-propagation for part of it.  (I assume `.L__unnamed_1:` is in `.rodata`, but I haven't checked on https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86106

Answer (score 3):

`&str.to_string()` builds the `String`s backing `Vec` through a call on `&[u8]::to_owned()` which in turn calls `&[u8]::to_vec()` and ends up calling `RawVec::with_capacity_in`.

`String::new()` and `String::default()` create the `Vec` through `Vec::new()` which internally wraps `RawVec::SELF`, a const value.

You can reduce the example to

```
fn slice_to_vec() -> Vec<u8> {
    let b: &[u8] = &[];
    let v = b.to_vec();
}
// example::slice_to_vec:
//        mov     rax, rdi
//        mov     qword ptr [rdi], 1
//        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
//        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 8], xmm0
//        ret
```

vs

```
pub fn vec() -> Vec<u8> {
    Vec::new()
}
// example::vec:
//        mov     rax, rdi
//        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
//        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rcx
//        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
//        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 8], xmm0
//        ret
//
// .L__unnamed_1:
//         .asciz  "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"
```

I can't explain *why* this happens, but 1.52 happened to [upgrade the LLVM version](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#compiler-4) used by Rust, so perhaps that changed the generated assembly.

Comment: Found this issue [#86106](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86106)